# Will the query inside the ORDER BY be repeatedly evaluated?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have several database objects which need to extract a single record (like TOP 1) from a table, but the priority for which one is chosen depends on a BIT value in a settings table, and that settings table will contain only one row.

I have written a view which will perform the required functionality:

```
CREATE VIEW TopOrganisationAddresses AS
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  OrganisationID,
            AddressID,
            CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM GlobalSettings WHERE DeliveryAddressInReports=1) THEN IsDeliveryAddress ELSE IsInvoiceAddress END AS OrderFirst,
            CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM GlobalSettings WHERE DeliveryAddressInReports=1) THEN IsInvoiceAddress ELSE IsDeliveryAddress END AS OrderSecond
    FROM OrganisationAddresses
)

SELECT OrganisationID, AddressID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrganisationID
                            ORDER BY OrderFirst DESC, OrderSecond DESC) AS [Row]
FROM cte
```

**Will the SELECT * FROM GlobalSettings queries be evaluated for every fow in the OrganisationAddresses table?**  If so this would be incredibly wasteful as it is only a static value that isn't going to change.

Comment: The two sub-queries are identical did you mean to write a different WHERE condition in one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it could be optimised away but you can perhaps just use another `cte` which does that `SELECT` to guarantee it e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW TopOrganisationAddresses AS
WITH cteg AS 
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM GlobalSettings WHERE DeliveryAddressInReports=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS dair
),
cte AS
(
    SELECT  OrganisationID,
            AddressID,
            CASE WHEN cteg.dair = 1 THEN IsDeliveryAddress ELSE IsInvoiceAddress END AS OrderFirst,
            CASE WHEN cteg.dair = 1 THEN IsInvoiceAddress ELSE IsDeliveryAddress END AS OrderSecond
    FROM OrganisationAddresses
    CROSS JOIN cteg
)

SELECT OrganisationID, AddressID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrganisationID
                            ORDER BY OrderFirst DESC, OrderSecond DESC) AS [Row]
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server should be smart enough to run the queries only once.  The optimizer should recognize exactly what you do -- that these are constant values.  For instance, the following query returns the same value for the `id`:

```
with cte as (
      select v.*,
             (select top 1 newid() from (values (1), (2)) v2(n) order by newid()) as val
      from (values (1), (2)) v(n)
     )
select *
from cte;
```

([Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fc248ea6a248d186193e957e82d9753) is a db<>fiddle.)

If you wanted to be sure that these are evaluated only once, you can move the logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
CREATE VIEW TopOrganisationAddresses AS
    SELECT oa.OrganisationID, oa.AddressID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oa.OrganisationID
                               ORDER BY v.OrderFirst DESC, v.OrderSecond DESC
                              ) AS [Row]
    FROM OrganisationAddresses oa CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM GlobalSettings WHERE DeliveryAddressInReports = 1) THEN IsDeliveryAddress ELSE IsInvoiceAddress END,,
                  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM GlobalSettings WHERE DeliveryAddressInReports = 1) THEN IsInvoiceAddress ELSE IsDeliveryAddress END)
         ) v(OrderFirst, OrderSecond);
```